# How to set updates periodically?

Tags: updates

If I'm tired of do `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`, how can I tell my Ubuntu system to update automatically given a period of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open *Software & Updates* from Dash

   [image: Dash -> software & updates]
2. On the new window open the *Updates* tab

   [image: Updates tab -> set your values]
3. Now you will see the *Automatically check for Updates* option between others.
   Select your values, enter your password and done!

Comment: Thats 'Automatically Check for Updates' - you still have to press a button to activate it ;-)